# Having Issue on Comparing Two DataFarne (Parent and Derived DF) in Pandas

Tags: pandas

Can you please take a look at this Pandas in Notebook and let me know why I am getting the `ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects` error when trying to compare two data frames.

```
import pandas as pd

series = [('Stranger Things', 3, 'Millie'),
          ('Game of Thrones', 8, 'Emilia'), ('La Casa De Papel', 4, 'Sergio'),
          ('Westworld', 3, 'Evan Rachel'), ('Stranger Things', 3, 'Millie'),
         ('La Casa De Papel', 4, 'Sergio')]

df = pd.DataFrame(series, columns=['Name', 'Seasons', 'Actor'])
print(df)
```

[image]

```
ddf = df.drop_duplicates(subset =['Name', 'Seasons', 'Actor'], keep = 'first')
print(ddf)
```

[image]

Now when I want to compare the `ddf` (the cleaned data) with `df` and get the differences like this

```
print(df.compare(ddf))
```

But I am getting this error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects

Comment: from the `df.compare` docs it looks like the two dfs have to have the same number of rows and columns `Can only compare identically-labeled (i.e. same shape, identical row and column labels) DataFrames`. Is your goal to get a new df with all the rows that are in `df` but not `ddf`?

Comment: Thanks mitoRibo, is there any other solution to find the differences between two data frames?

Comment: what do you want your output to be? The rows in `df` but not in `ddf`?

Comment: Exactly! I need to get rows that are not in `ddf`

Comment: `diff_df = df.loc[df.index.difference(ddf.index)]` here's one way to do it using the indices which can behave like sets. please consider accepting @Naveed's answer below since it technically answered your original question

Answer (score 0):

in your case the shape of the two DF are not same i.e., ddf has 6 rows, and df has 3 rows

from the documentation [compare](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html?highlight=compare#pandas.DataFrame.compare)

> **Raises:  ValueError**
> When the two DataFrames don’t have identical labels or shape.
>
> Can only compare identically-labeled (i.e. same shape, identical row
> and column labels) DataFrames

Comment: what is the point of this compare then? if two things are IDENTICAL! why someone would wnat to compare them!?

Comment: Shape and Label needs to be same, not the values or content